# Power BI. Execute SQL Server stored procedure with a user parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powerbi

I have a Power BI report and a stored procedure with a `@DateFrom` parameter which returns a number of rows. I want to allow user to choose the date which will be passed to stored procedure. (Using DirectQuery mode)

I have fount zero solutions to this simple task. Maybe I don't understand anything, but it's quite a common problem, which seems to be ignored by Power BI developers.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
EXEC [rpt].[sp_rpt_bids_statictics_2] @DateFrom = '20160101'
```

Now I want to allow user to choose that very date, fore example '20160501' and then the query will be the following:

```
EXEC [rpt].[sp_rpt_bids_statictics_2] @DateFrom = '20160501'
```

is it possible in Microsoft Power BI?

Comment: Can't you use a variable whose value is set by the user?

Comment: How should I do this? I have a simple window, when I create a datasource. There are 3 text fields there:ServerName, DatabaseName, sql-query.
That's all, where should I create a variable and insert it into my sql-query?

Comment: This scenario is not supported at present AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution.

1. Add a parameter and allow load for it. (for example its name is Query_param_1)
2. Create query in Import mode (only this mode allows it)
3. Then open extendet editor for created query
4. Edit "query part:
5. [Query="EXEC [rpt].[sp_rpt_bids_statictics_2] @DateFrom = '"Query_param_1"'"]
6. Now it works with the parameter, chosen by user.

Comment: That's unexpected, given that import mode imports fixed static data (as opposed to direct query)

Comment: I was literally just about to abandon Power BI over this until I found this answer